# <il> is pushed down when border appears

Tags: html, css

It is hard to learn "float" "overflow" "clear" and some other properties so please help me find good online websites to learn these properties ..

I opened some websites to make designs like them I found http://wix.com I admired its nav bar so i tried to make like it but i had a problem when mouse is over the il it is pushed down to show the top border how can I fix that 
thanks and I am sorry for my weak English

```css
body {
 background-color: lightblue;
}


ul {
 
 position: fixed;
 list-style-type: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 padding-top: 8px;
 padding-bottom: 8px;
 display: block;
 background-color:  #666666;
 transition:background-color, 1s;
}


ul:hover {
 background-color: #333;
}

il {
 transition:border-top,1s;
 float: left;
 padding-right: 10px;
 border-right: 1px solid white;
 
}

il:hover {
 border-top:5px solid lightblue; 
}

#navl {
 font-family: Trebuchet MS’, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 letter-spacing: 3px;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

pre{
 
 font-family: Courier New,Courier,Lucida Sans Typewriter,Lucida Typewriter,monospace;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 font-size: 30px;
 text-align: center; 
 color: white;
 margin-top: 150px;
}

#plans:link, #plans:visited {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 14px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 110px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: Courier New,Courier,Lucida Sans Typewriter,Lucida Typewriter,monospace;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<ul>
<il><a id="navl" href="index.html">Home</a></il>
<il><a id="navl" href="Plans.html">Plans</a></il>
<il><a id="navl" href="About.html">About</a></il>
<il><a id="navl" href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a></il>
</ul>

<pre>test</pre>

<a id="plans" href="plans.html">Plans</a>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Typos in your code `<il>`

Answer (score 0):

At first, replace those `il` with `li`, and add this style to your `li`:

```
li {
 border-top: 5px solid transparent; 
}
```

And in `ul`, instead of `padding-top:8px` add `padding-top:3px`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is because the border adds height to the element. To correct it, you can either remove height from the main element or shift it up:

```
li:hover {
  margin-top: -5px; //shifts the element up 5px
}
```

or you can have an invisible border as [Teuta mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38337928/5937428) that gets "covered up" by the new border.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link with a little work around I did.  I removed the padding top in ul. Changed the il to li. Because actually it is 'li' not 'il'. And I added a border top in li.

Here is the css code I changed.

```
ul:hover {
    background-color: #666666;
}

li {
    transition:border-top,1s;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    border-top:5px solid #666666;
}

li:hover {
    border-top:5px solid lightblue; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7x7dy3jt/